# Why Single Instance Logic in Release Mode is failed?

Tags: c#, wpf

Here is my code 
**I tried in Debug Mode. It works.
While in release does not why? Its a WPF application**

This piece of code i put in Main Method for checking if a application is running or not. I want single instance to be running only. I copied this code from Stack Overflow only.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    const string MutexName = "{8F6F0AC4-B9A1-45fd-A8CF-72F04E6BDE8F}";
    try
    {
        Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, MutexName);

        if (mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true))
        {
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            //Here Application logic
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Application is alreadey running.");
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't release mutex until application logic is finished. And you probably don't want `true` in mutex constructor, because of `WaitOne`.

Comment: Include a [mcve], check your debug/release config for differences, explain what you mean by *"is failed"*, etc... as it is now, this question is unlikely to be answered.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer I hope you have tested this piece of code.

Comment: I don't know why people are marking it down

Comment: @Sinatr thanks. I don't know what makes it failing exactly. I posted an answer can you please test it some time

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact reason. But this modification works

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {

        const string MutexName = "8F6F0AC4-B9A1-45fd-A8CF-72F04E6BDE8F";
        try
        {

            Mutex mutex;

            if (!Mutex.TryOpenExisting(MutexName, out mutex))
            {
                mutex = new Mutex(true,MutexName);
                var app = new App();
                app.Run();
            }
            else
            {

                Environment.Exit(1);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }

    }
```